# sscanf function in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm working in my C program and I have a doubt about how to use the sscanf function.

I have to get from a string like `something$HOME/something2` three strings: the first one has to contain "something", the second one "HOME" and the third one "/something2".
But also it has to be able to split `$HOME` or `$HOME/something`, or `something$HOME`...

What I wrote was something like that:

```
sscanf(str,"%m[^$]$%m[_a-zA-Z0-9]%*m", &ant, &act, &sig);
```

But for the cases `$HOME`, `$HOME/something`, `something$HOME...` it takes very strange strings.  Any ideas of what can I put on my sscanf to get the other values by NULL in case they don't exist?

Comment: `sscanf` format string is *not* a regular expression. If you want regular expressions functionality you would need to use a dedicated library.

Comment: `"…%*m"` at the end of the format string is broken; you need an `s` or `[…]` (scan set) after the `m`.  You aren't testing the return value from `sscanf()`; it would tell you that something is wrong, probably by returning EOF, maybe by returning just 2 when you need it to return 3.

Comment: Note that none of the `sscanf()` conversion specifications accepts an empty string, so you can't handle 'possibly missing parts' with a single call to `sscanf()`.  One of the advantages of using `sscanf()` is that you can try different format strings on the same data until you find one that parses the data as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you should *not* use `sscanf` for that. Your input seems to be a shell command line argument and you seem to want implement variable expansion.

For that, you have to write *your own* parser that would parse the expression, identify and do variable expansion. It's not a job for `scanf` - it's a job for your custom loop where you inspect each and every character in a string.

There's a utility with like *exactly* that functionality called `envsubst`. You could inspect [its source gettext/envsubst.c](https://github.com/bennoleslie/gettext/blob/master/gettext-runtime/src/envsubst.c#L236). You could also take a look at [wordexp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html); however, `wordexp` function is a way broader function.